# Proyecto recién creado en Xamarin, no toque el código, ayer funciono bien la implementación y hoy ya no funciona

Tags: android, c#, app, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Estoy ocupando Visual Studio 2017 community
mi ambiente de desarrollo no esta bien configurado, la implementación es inconsistente e inestable, a veces funciona, a veces no. la única forma de que funcione es iniciar el emulador de visual studio para android antes de compilar, pero creo que no es lo ideal y tampoco es normal.

los pasos que sigo para crear el proyecto son :

```
Archivo>Nuevo>Proyecto>plantillas>Visual C#>Cross-Platform>Cross-Platform App (Xamarin)>Aplicacion en blanco
```

Tecnología de `IU:Xamarin.forms` Estrategia de uso compartido de código: Proyecto compartido

si necesitan mas información solo pidanmelo

aquí esta la salida:

```
1>------ Operación Compilar iniciada: proyecto: AppUnap.Android, configuración: Debug Any CPU ------
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\tabbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\toolbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml
1>  AppUnap.Android -> C:\Users\marti\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\AppUnap\AppUnap\AppUnap.Android\bin\Debug\AppUnap.Android.dll
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\tabbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\toolbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\tabbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\toolbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml
2>Iniciando la implementación de 7" KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet ...
2>Iniciando el emulador 7" KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet ...
2>An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
2>Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
========== Compilar: 1 correctos, 0 incorrectos, 0 actualizados, 0 omitidos ==========
========== Implementar: 0 correctos, 1 incorrectos, 0 omitidos ==========
```

Comment: ya revisate el log: "See full exception on logs for more details."

Answer (score 1):

**Solución práctica**

1. Clean && ReBuild.
2. Herramientas -> "Visual Studio Emulator for Android".
3. En esa pantalla selecciona el emulador que necesitas e inícialo.
4. Luego al costado de la flecha verde donde le das play para iniciar la aplicación, selecciona el mismo emulador.
5. Dale un Deploy, revisa el emulador y tu app debería estar ahí.

**En caso el emulador no levante:**

1. Ve al administrador de Hyper-V.
2. Elimina la máquina virtual que te está dando problemas.
3. En Visual Studio, Herramientas -> "Visual Studio Emulator for Android".
4. Creas nuevamente el emulador.
5. Compilas y que la fuerza os acompañe.

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo.

Selecciona tu proyecto con click derecho, luego click a la opción `Implementar` y luego solo revisa tu emulador (dispositivo virtual).

La app debería estar instalada ya ahí.